# How to load Image data from s3 bucket to sagemaker notebook?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I just started to use aws sagemaker. I tried to import images from my s3 bucket to sagemaker notebook. But I can't import images to the notebook. my image location is **s3://my_bucket/train** how can I import the train folder from the given path to my sagemaker notebook. I've gone through some of  the solution in here and the solutions are for CSV file. All the images in my S3 bucket are in .jpeg format.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the solutions in here"? Are you missing a link, perhaps?

Comment: Well. I've gone through almost "all" the solutions. By the way, if you have something. It would a great help if you tell me.

Comment: I don't have a solution off the top of my head, I was just reviewing posts to improve them (and increase their chances of being solved!). I still believe you should probably try to describe a bit better what you tried specifically, what sources you have used for help and so on. Otherwise people will think "if he tried "all", then why bother with my idea".

Answer (score 6):

you could use `s3fs` to easily access your bucket as well as an image file in it.

```py
from PIL import Image
import s3fs

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

# To List 5 files in your accessible bucket
fs.ls('s3://bucket-name/data/')[:5]

# open it directly
with fs.open(f's3://bucket-name/data/image.png') as f:
    display(Image.open(f))
```

Comment: Add this line on top : from PIL import Image

Comment: thanks! I will note that this also works for other problems, I had trouble with an XML file and this has fixed it

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to download images from S3 bucket to local SageMaker instance for training the model. If you are trying to pull them for data exploration/analysis you can use [aws cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) from your SageMaker notebook. You can use following command to download a sample image. This will copy `sample.jpg` to `images` directory in your `pwd`.

`aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket/train/sample.jpg ./images/sample.jpg`

Try looking at [amazon-sagemaker-examples](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms) repo to learn how to work with image formats on SageMaker.

Comment: I've gone through the repo you mention. I wonder how can I convert my train folder which has almost 40k images to .lst format. They mention about im2rec.py file to convert file but at first, I have to access the file from s3 right? or Should I download the file from s3 to the local machine and then after convert again upload to s3 it sounds so boring and inefficient. Could you enlighten me more?

Comment: What algorithm are you using with these images? If it is SageMaker built-in [Image Classification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/image-classification.html), input can be in both RecordIO and image formats. Refer Image Classification doc link and notebooks to know how to create the list file depending on type of problem you are working with e.g. binary or multi-label classification. im2rec.py is running locally (on SageMaker), therefore cannot take input from the S3 bucket. To generate the RecordIO file, you need to download the images and then use the im2rec tool.

Comment: Thank you for share the aws CLI command appending, which I have directly used in a SageMaker Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Which SageMaker sample notebook(s) are you trying to use?

If your input data is in S3 bucket, you don't have to download it to your SageMaker notebook instance. This example shows that data is uploaded to S3 bucket: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/imageclassification_caltech/Image-classification-fulltraining.ipynb

For training purposes, you can configure `s3_train` to your input data bucket.

And here's an inference on the image input format for the built-in image classification.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet of code below will help you load your image folder from your s3 bucket to your SageMaker instance;

```py
import boto3 
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError # Not necessary

# Remember to enter the cirrect bucket region below
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-west-2') 
# Replace the place holder with your correct bucket name
bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket') 
for my_bucket_object in bucket.objects.all():    
    key = my_bucket_object.key    
    print(key)    
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(key)):           
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(key))

# The following is basically for exception handling and not necessary to include     
    try:         
        bucket.download_file(key, key)     
    except ClientError as e:         
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":             
            print("No object with this key.")        
        else:             
            raise
```

Alternatively, you can also try running the following script from your Sagemaker notebook cell;

```
!aws s3 cp s3://$my_bucket//train/images train/images/ --recursive
```

The solution is from [this website](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2020/01/aws-sagemaker-data-handling/).

[Documentation on using `cp`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).